# Proving that a Graph without 6-cycles has subgraph without 4-cycle

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

I am currently trying to prove that for every graph G such that the 6-cycle $C_6$ is not a subgraph of G, there exists a subgraph H with $|E(H)|\geq|E(G)|/2$ (with E(G) being the edge set of G) which doesnt contain a 4-Cycle.

I first tried to attack this by constructing subgraphs using random 2-colorings and then deleting monocolored edges, but this yielded a worse approximation for the size of the edge set.

Furthermore, I tried to rewrite the claim (however i am unsure if this is even correct):$$ex(n, C_6)\leq2ex(n, C_4)$$
I found a result (by Erdős, Rényi and Sós among others) which says that $ex(n,C_4)=1/2n^{3/2}+o(n^{3/2})$ and $ex(n,C_6)=(n^{4/3})$, which would then imply (assuming i reworded the claim correctly) that there are two positive constants a,b with b<1 such that $a\cdot n^{4/3}≤n^{3/2}(1+2b)$, which is equivalent to $a\leq n^{1/6}(1+2b)$. This above result is the only one I found in my graph theory material (not just my own notes, but also the lecture notes and the lecture script), which is why it seems to me that i am on the right path.

However, this is where i am unsure if it would already be proven and if not i am a bit lost on what to do next, so any help would be appreciated!

Comment: You should use MathJax to phrase your question correctly. [Here’s a guide.](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using a random deletion argument, try a greedy deletion argument: we need to delete at most half of the edges and destroy all the $C_4$'s. In a $C_6$-free graph, we can pair the edges which appear in multiple $C_4$'s so that if an edge appears in multiple $C_4$'s, then its mate appears in exactly the same $C_4$'s. Deleting exactly one edge in each pair yields a graph where every edge is in at most one $C_4$, after which we need only delete a quarter of the edges to remove the rest of the $C_4$'s.

This is a nice fact which shows that
$$ \text{ex}(n,C_6) \geq \text{ex}(n,\{C_4,C_6\}) \geq \text{ex}(n,C_6)/2 .$$

Comment: Could you expand a bit on the pairing of the edges in multiple $C_4$'s? 
I can see that each pair of $C_4$'s must have at least two edges in common (because otherwise there is a $C_6$), however dont we also have to entertain the idea that they could have three edges in common? This would leave us with three pairs, so we would delete two edges if we follow the argumentation, which in turn might mean we delete too many edges.

Comment: @Zerakiin if two $C_4$'s have at least three edges in common, then they must be the same $C_4$. To see why the pairing exists, just draw out what happens if we try to have three $C_4$'s whose intersection is exactly one edge.